# Output 3gp audio/video in php

Tags: php, android, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem that I can not solve.
I use RewriteEngine in my `.htaccess` to access some videos. I need to export them for use in `android`.

My `.htaccess:`

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*)\.amr$ api.php?cmd=getmp3&hash=$1 [L]
```

In `api.php`

```
$__GB->getSafemp3($_GET['hash']);
```

And feature code:

```
header('Content-Type: video/3gpp');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=' . $fetch['new_name']);
header('Content-length: '.filesize($path));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

readfile($path);
```

With the URL directly works perfectly, but not RewriteRule

Edit:
I've fixed the problem, i changed the feature code for this:

```
header('Location: ' . $path.$fetch['new_name']); //$path.$fetch['new_name'] is the file directory, ex: /music/audio.3gp
```